# Clicking on a list of <li> only works on the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few li elements and I want each of them to be clickable. This is what I have:

```
<li  id="stream-object" data-stream="val1">
<li  id="stream-object" data-stream="val2">
<li  id="stream-object" data-stream="val3">
```

and my jquery

```
$("#stream-object").click(function(){
var stream_link=$(this).data("stream");
$("#main_stream").attr("data",stream_link);
});
```

But this only works on the first li.

Comment: You can use one time same id. Your ids should be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior as **ID's in HTML must be unique**, You can use a common class then use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

> Selects all elements with the given class.

*HTML*

```
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val1">
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val2">
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val3">
```

*Script*

```
$(".stream-object").click(function(){
    var stream_link=$(this).data("stream");
    $("#main_stream").attr("data",stream_link);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

ID (`#`) **must** be unique for page use clasess (`.`) instead

```
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val1">
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val2">
<li class="stream-object" data-stream="val3">

$(".stream-object").click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

An id should be unique. Instead use classes

```js
$(".stream-object").click(function(){
  var stream_link=$(this).data("stream");
  $("#main_stream").attr("data",stream_link);
  alert( $(this).html()+' is clicked' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="stream-object" data-stream="val1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="stream-object" data-stream="val2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="stream-object" data-stream="val3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```